# How to use dynamic keywork to work with entity framework

Tags: asp.net

I am using .net framework 3.5 framework & for database operations entity framework. So, to fetch the data i am using LINQ queries & returns a resultset in a list.
e.g

```
public class Emp
{
 public int CD{get;set;}
 public string Name{get;set;}
}


public List<Emp> GetServTypeForPromotionDue()
{
        return (from a in Context.TableName
                    select new Emp{ a.CD, a.NAME });

}
```

I am planning to migrate from 3.5 to 4.0. I have heard about dynamic keyword in .net 4.0. Can i make use of 'dynamic' keyword in order to remove the Class Emp & without creating Anonymous methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *could* use `dynamic` for this (e.g. returning `List<dynamic>`, and building an `ExpandoObject` in the select clause), but I wouldn't recommend it. You'd lose compile-time type safety, Intellisense etc for little benefit. What do you believe you'd *gain* from using `dynamic`? Just removing a few lines of code?

EDIT: Example of using dynamic:

```
public List<dynamic> GetServTypeForPromotionDue()
{
        return (from a in Context.TableName
                select (dynamic) (new { a.CD, a.NAME })).ToList();
}
```

Or...

```
public List<dynamic> GetServTypeForPromotionDue()
{
        return (from a in Context.TableName
                select (dynamic) (new ExpandoObject { a.CD, a.NAME })).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Can u convert GetServTypeForPromotionDue() above function using dynamic keyword   thanx

Comment: @Ulhas: Okay, I've given two options... but I still wouldn't recommend doing it.

Comment: Ok I have heard about Tuple class in .net 4.0. It is type-safe can i make use of that class?

Comment: Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types. i got this error from above code